# On selecting menu Item from the side menu TabBar gets disappear?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have burger button (menu button) in almost all vc and my main screen is tabBarController. Currently I'm getting the side menu when tapping on the Button .On choosing a menu, it shows the desired vc but the bottom tab bar is not there which was there before i select menu item. I want to have the bottom tabbar in entire pages also in pages from the side menu. I.'m using `SWRevealViewController` for burger menu

How can I acheive this? Please help me.

The code I'm using in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is:

```
if indexPath.row == 1 {
    let destinationVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
    let newFrontVc = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:destinationVc!)
    revealViewController.pushFrontViewController(newFrontVc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: can you check this link
https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/files/275828/SWTabBarSwift2.zip

Comment: @RatneshShukla already been through that code...he is using containerViewController but when i initialize  the container object it gives me error "use of undeclare type"

Answer (score 0):

You have to add tabBarController between navBarVc and frontVc

```
let navBarVc = UINavigationController()
let tabBarVc = navBarVc.childViewControllers[0] as! tabBarController
    tabBarVc.selectedViewController = yourVc
```

How about that.